# output JSON array jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I get this JSON array from a REST API via AJAX:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
    "language_code": "es",
    },
    {
    "language_code": "gl",
    },
    {
    "language_code": "pt",
    }
  ]
}
```

Within the AJAX success function I would like to `alert` each `language_code`. For some reason it's only working for the first item "es".

Here's the code:

```
 success: function(json) {

 $(json.results).each(function(item) {
    alert($(this)[item].language_code);
 });

 }
```

The each loop works and alerts "0", "1" and "2" if I do something like this: `alert(item);` - however, in the upper form it only reads the first item and then returns an error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: alert($(this).language_code); ?

Comment: Nooo, it's `item.language_code`, as `$(this)` shouldn't be used here

Comment: that gives me 3x "undefined" :(

Comment: `alert(item.language_code);`

Comment: And note, `$(el).each(function(index, item) {...`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/38kkhLL2/

Comment: @adeneo: That did it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$.each(json.results, function(key, val) {
    alert( val.language_code );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You would need to add another iteration block to get the all sub values. This would work for multiple nesting.

```
$.each(json,function(i) {
   $.each(json[i],function(x) // yields each child in 'results'
   {
      alert(json[i][x]["language_code"]);
   });
 });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rv3wwpsf/4/